# How to refresh single page application with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a single page application, and I want to reload, but whenever I run `window.location.reload(true);`, it refreshes to the homepage. For example, if I run it from `www.mywebsite.com/test/1`, it will open `www.mywebsite.com`, I simply want it to refresh to `www.mywebsite.com/test/1`, and I want it to happen from server, not from cache. Any ideas how to do it with pure JS?

Comment: `window.location.replace("www.mywebsite.com/test/1")` to reload your site. I don't know whats about caching

Comment: _"it will open www.mywebsite.com"_, if you mean your location ends up being `.com/` instead of `.com/test/1` than you might have redirects in place that redirect (like 301 redirect) not found paths to `/`. If so you need to replace those with url rewrites (like apache's  mod_rewrite).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
window.location = 'www.mywebsite.com/test/1'
```

It will still reload the page, but as long as your JS redraws based on the URL it should work.

IMHO a single page app should never call reload.  You just draw and clear elements on the page.

Comment: As an added note, if you include some query on the end like:  window.location = "www.mywebsite.com/test/1?nocache=" + (new Date()).getTime(); It should cause the browser to bypass the cache.  Keep in mind, this is likely browser dependent, meaning it may work for some, but not others.

Comment: The issue you are having is that a single page app only has one real URL.  When you reload the page, via window.location= or via location.reload it resets all of your state variables, and your javascript is re-executed.  You need to pass some parameter to your JS app that tells your app to redraw at the location, not reset to the home page.  An example of this in a framework is backbone.js routers https://cdnjs.com/libraries/backbone.js/tutorials/what-is-a-router.  The difference is in a "normal" website, each pages is a different file, in a JS single page app, you just have one page.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried simple location.reload() ?